# Finding $\alpha$ and $\omega$-limit set by just sketching trajectories

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following non-linear ODE system:

$x'= y+x(1-x^2-y^2)$

$y' = -x+y(1-x^2-y^2)$

and I would like to find the $\alpha$ and $\omega$-limit set for the vector field associated to this ODE system $X ((x,y)) = (y+x(1-x^2-y^2),-x+y(1-x^2-y^2))$.

First of all, I found out that whenever $z\in \{(x,y): x^2+y^2=1\}$ we have $X((x,y)) = (y,-x), $ so that $(x,y) \perp X((x,y))$ and hence all trajectories on the circle will remain on the circle, since the vector field on these points is perpendicular to them.

I proceeded with linearization of the ODE via the Jacobian matrix. I found out that the unique point which solves $y+x(1-x^2-y^2) = 0$ and $-x+y(1-x^2-y^2)=0$ is the origin itself. Plugging the value of the Jacobian matrix at $(0,0$) gave me a matrix which type of trajectory is a spiral from the origin towards the circle $\{(x,y): x^2+y^2=1\}$ and so whenever $p$ is in the interior of this circle, its $\omega$-limit set will be the circle itself and $\alpha$-limit set will be the origin.

But via computational methods:

[image]

We see that the trajectories outside the circle will lean towards it too. How can I show that? Since there are no more critical points, I can't proceed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint.

$$
x\dot x = x y + x^2(1-x^2-y^2)\\
y\dot y =-y x + y^2(1-x^2-y^2) 
$$

adding both lines

$$
\frac 12 \frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2) = (x^2+y^2)(1-x^2-y^2)
$$

now calling $r^2 = x^2+y^2$ we have

$$
\frac 12\frac{d}{dt}\ln(r^2) = 1-r^2
$$
so for $r < 1$ we have that $r$ increases and for $r > 1$ we have that $r$ decreases etc.